# MSSQL Query - Sum only positive numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MSSQL query where I sum the value of columns.
For an example;

```
select SUM(column_a), SUM(column_b)
from table c
group by c_id
```

Now I need to sum only positive numbers, ignore negative numbers.
For an example:

```
Column A:
2
-2
4
2
```

The SUM function will give me result of 6 (2-2+4+2)
What I need it to do is to ignore the negative number (-2) and give me result of 8 (2+4+2)

I have 8 columns where I need it.

Answer (score 12):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when a > 0 then a else 0 end),
       sum(case when b > 0 then b else 0 end)
       ...
from tablename
```

Add `GROUP BY` if needed:

```
group by c_id
```

Comment: I really like this option.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT SUM(Number)
FROM   TableName 
WHERE  Number > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just not `select` them in your query with a simple `WHERE` clause?

```
WHERE  Number > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(column_a), sum(column_b) from table c where column_a>0 and column_b>0 group by c_id
```